# Wordpress takes several minutes to load

Tags: wordpress, performance

I have a WordPress install that was running perfectly for years - https://electrofx.com

no changes or updates were made and it has started taking several minutes to load a page.

I have tried debugging via the wp-config file method, no errors can be found there.

I have tried restoring to one of the old backups that I know was working, no change.

I have tried disabling all plugins and switching themes, no change.

I have tried setting up a test page that is not WordPress and can confirm my hosting server is OK.

At this point I am at a loss as to what else I can try, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (and in fact, all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which require users to go off-site to get more information are not useful to future visitors, particularly once the off-site resource changes. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking without needing to go off-site to find out. Please see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

When I have had similar issues, I checked the following:

- The status of the MySQL database: e.g., is the database full?
- The hard disk space of the server
- The PHP version of the server vs the required Wordpress version. If you have made no updates on PHP but have kept Wordpress up to date, this could cause processing issues
- Inefficient plugins that may not have been updated
- A query is taking a long time. You can check the slow query log to see. As an example, I had an e-commerce site that was super slow, due to an inefficient query for listing the products
- Check Google Pagespeed or other page speed test, to see how long the server response time is

It's not clear from your question whether 'no updates' means no plugin or core wordpress updates, or if you mean you haven't changed text / content on the site but have updated it.

Comment: I didn't update the plugins or WordPress for several months or the content.

Comment: pagespeed works well on a simple php info page but not on wordpress